# how to remove calls to github while installing node modules like node-sass@3.7.0 install

Tags: node.js, npm, node-sass

Hi I'm trying to have a local instance of node and npm which I manage to do using sinopia, but that still dose not solve my problem because  while installing modules like

```
node-sass@3.7.0 install <location>node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
[INFO] > node scripts/install.js
[INFO]
[ERROR] Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.7.0/win32-x64-46_binding.node":
```

I get the proxy error, which the only work around would be to substitute the call to github with a local service to that packages.

probably I would need to modify install.js file. But maybe there is a better way of doing it.

Or the question should be how do I change the "package.json" file for all the

```
"devDependencies": {
    "del": "~2.2.0",
    "gulp": "~3.9.1",
}
```

To pick those from local/internal repository.